# Navigation menu breaks for Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, navigation

This menu works perfectly in webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) but I cannot get the dropdown floating working in Firefox or IE, can someone shed light on this? Been on it for hours

http://jsfiddle.net/ERsrf/3/

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Large</a></li>
    <li><a>Large</a></li>
    <li>
        <a>Extra Large</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a>This seems</a></li>
            <li><a>To break in</a></li>
            <li><a>Firefox/IE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Extra Extra Large</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 160px;
    min-width: 100px;
    position:relative;
}
a {
    background: beige;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 0;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
ul li:hover > ul.dropdown {
    display: block;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover a {
    background: whiteSmoke;
}
```

Comment: If you remove _li > position: relative_, it breaks on chrome as well. So, your issue must be around there.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you accept my answer when you agree with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: I've changed the working example to use lower specifity on CSS selectors as well**
Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/kFTnG/4/

Several points of your approach:

- The reason for Fx & IE to put the `.dropdown li` on one line were the `display: inline-block; float: left;` properties
- Giving your parent `<li>` `display: table-cell` will nearly always make it --besides very small viewports-- 160px width
- `display: block;` together with `float` declaration on parent `<li>` is better for relative positioned descendant elements

Comment: Well, you've got to know how many list-items there are in your <ul>, than you can put width (100%/number of list-items) on the list-items and it works. But take care of the border properties, they would get added to width: 100% therefor I've moved it to the <a>s. Tested in Fx, IE, Chrome. See http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/kFTnG/6/